# Change ios iPad/iPhone project to library and merge into universal app

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app

I have two projects: One made for the iPad and one for the iPhone. The iPad version is using CoreData and .xib files.

Both project use CocoaPods.

I want to convert each project to a library, make a new universal app, link the two libraries into it and then set the AppDelegate class according to the device.

How can I convert my project to a library ?